# Let $a>1$ and $f,g,h \colon [-a,a] \to \Bbb R$ be twice differentiable function such that..

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

[image]

I will be highly obliged if someone provides explanation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) is impossible: $ f'(0)=0, h(0)\ne0$, so $h\ne f'$;

(C) and (D) is also impossible: $ f(0)=0, -g'(0)\ne 0,$, so $f\ne -g'$

(B) is the only choice

For example $a=\sqrt2, c=\dfrac1{\sqrt3}$, and

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{12}(x^2-2), \qquad   g=f'=\frac{x}{3}(x^2-1),\qquad h=g'=x^2-\frac13 $$